# how can i sum two table column items group by month using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by, sum

Table A and Table B consists of three fields like pr_name,amount,date.

```
[same]
pr_name amount date

paper   100   2017-01-10
paper     50   2017-01-30
pen    100  2017-05-10
pen     200   2017-05-30
paper   500   2017-11-21
```

table B as same A.expected resultset is:

```
Month_name Table A Table B

january    150     150
february    0       0
......
......
may        300    300
....
november   500    500
```

```
Error:

  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "rowid": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT CASE rowid WHEN 1 THEN 'jan' WHEN 2 THEN 'feb' WHEN 3 THEN 'mar'  WHEN  4 THEN 'apr' WHEN 5 THEN 'may' WHEN 6 THEN 'jun'   WHEN 7 THEN 'jul' WHEN 8 THEN 'aug' WHEN 9 THEN 'sep'   WHEN  10 THEN 'oct' WHEN 11 THEN 'nov' WHEN 12 THEN 'dec' END as Month_name,(SELECT SUM(e_amount) FROM RecordA WHERE strftime('%Y', e_dates) = '2017' AND CAST(strftime('%m',e_dates) AS Integer) = c.rowid) AS 'Table A',(SELECT SUM(i_amount) FROM RecordB WHERE strftime('%Y',i_dates) = '2017' AND CAST(strftime('%m', e_dates) AS Integer) = c.rowid) AS 'Table B'FROM RecordA cWHERE rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 12
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(near "rowid": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT CASE rowid WHEN 1 THEN 'jan' WHEN 2 THEN 'feb' WHEN 3 THEN 'mar'  WHEN  4 THEN 'apr' WHEN 5 THEN 'may' WHEN 6 THEN 'jun'   WHEN 7 THEN 'jul' WHEN 8 THEN 'aug' WHEN 9 THEN 'sep'   WHEN  10 THEN 'oct' WHEN 11 THEN 'nov' WHEN 12 THEN 'dec' END as Month_name,(SELECT SUM(e_amount) FROM RecordA WHERE strftime('%Y', e_dates) = '2017' AND CAST(strftime('%m',e_dates) AS Integer) = c.rowid) AS 'Table A',(SELECT SUM(i_amount) FROM RecordB WHERE strftime('%Y',i_dates) = '2017' AND CAST(strftime('%m', e_dates) AS Integer) = c.rowid) AS 'Table B'FROM RecordA cWHERE rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
#################################################################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the month name from sqlite using strftime so we will have to translate 1, 2, 3 ... into month names using a case statement. To be sure we get all months even if there are no data for a particular month, we can just generate numers 1 to 12 with `rowid`. For this use any table which has at least 12 rows. Then with subqueries we can get the desired summary data for these months:

```
SELECT CASE c.rowid WHEN 1 THEN 'jan' WHEN 2 THEN 'feb' WHEN 3 THEN 'mar'
  WHEN  4 THEN 'apr' WHEN 5 THEN 'may' WHEN 6 THEN 'jun' 
  WHEN 7 THEN 'jul' WHEN 8 THEN 'aug' WHEN 9 THEN 'sep' 
  WHEN  10 THEN 'oct' WHEN 11 THEN 'nov' WHEN 12 THEN 'dec' END as Month_name,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TableA WHERE strftime('%Y', "date") = '2017'
 AND CAST(strftime('%m', "date") AS Integer) = c.rowid) AS 'Table A',
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TableB WHERE strftime('%Y', "date") = '2017'
 AND CAST(strftime('%m', "date") AS Integer) = c.rowid) AS 'Table B'
FROM TableX c
WHERE c.rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```

Note: the CAST is not necessary but it's better to make that explicit. TableX can be TableA.

Comment: That's "no such table". Did you substitute your own table names for TableA, TableB and TableX?

Comment: Yes.i changed only table names TableA,TableB and not change in TableX.

Comment: Then change TableX to a nice little domain table you have with 12 or more rows or, if you don't have any, to the same table as TableA.

Comment: Same error happen.i have 2 tables with 12 rows and tableX changed table A but cant work.

Comment: Posted error message in question.what i did mistake.

Comment: Replace the first and last rowid by c.rowid. And you're missing some spaces before the last FROM and WHERE.

Comment: Cool.After correction working .show two columns column monthname,table A created.table B column  not displayed.